# How to Draw circle path like this in d3?

Tags: d3.js, canvas

I want to draw circle path like image below in d3.

[image]

I try this but not working.

```
const patternCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const patternContext = patternCanvas.getContext('2d');
    patternCanvas.width = 50;
    patternCanvas.height = 50;
    patternContext.fillStyle = '#fff';
    patternContext.fillRect(0, 0, patternCanvas.width, patternCanvas.height);
    patternContext.stroke();
    const pattern = this.context.createPattern(patternCanvas, 'repeat');
    this.context.fillStyle = pattern;
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.closePath();
    this.context.fill();
    this.context.stroke();
```

Thank for your help!

Comment: draw the circles via the arc method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc

Comment: @flowtron I'm new on canvas path, Can I have sample code to do that? Thank you

Comment: On the page I linked there's a bunch of examples.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation & examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc

The basic circle outline is done like so:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

The basic filled circle is done like so:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = '#888'
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
```